# Search on site throws 'access denied' error or shows no results

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, search-scope

In our to level site collection (which is a portal), and 
I've set the search center to my enterprise search site collection: /sites/search/pages. When I log in through ADFS and try to search anything with search box in top-right corner, I'm getting 'access denied' error.

But when I'm logged in as site collection administrator through active directory from intranet, I can perform enter search term and I'm taken to results page, but unfortunately it is always empty. Funny thing is, that when I search same term from this result page after changing selection from 'This site' to 'All sites', I'm taken to the search center results page and results are displayed correctly.

I'd also like to enable anonymous users to perform search from on our top level site collection, since anonymous access is active. I enabled anonymous access on search center site collection, but still I'm asked to log in when I try to perform search from site collection. I can perform anonymous search directly from search center, and results are correctly security-trimmed.

How can I solve those issues?

### EDIT 1:

Our platform is SharePoint 2010 Server Enterprise.

Comment: There are a LOT of issues in this... Start with the basics - what version of SharePoint are you using (i.e. 2007 WSS or 2010 Enterprise...)

Comment: @DaveWise: I edited my question with platform information, if more information are required, please let me know.

Comment: Any chance you can replicate the error and check the ULS logs to see what those might report to give you any clues? Use some ULS Log viewer instead of a regular text editor

Answer (score 1):

Check that ADFS identities have permission to access /sites/search/pages (identities are different if they come through ADFS compared to NTML for example, even if Resource Provider would be the exact same AD in both cases)

Comment: Can't really get hold of the issues in second paragraph, could you post URL's to which you are redirected when you do the search.

Comment: Answer to you first question is yes - ADFS Identities can access `/sites/search/pages`. And when I perform search on my root site collection, I'm redirected to `_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx`